# Difference of location of same files in ArcGIS Pro and QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro

I am trying to spatial join two shapefiles, one is a line and one is a point. But I have been unable to do so, in ArcGIS Pro I get an attribute field error and in QGIS I get Null values.

When I tried Select by location in QGIS, it is not selecting any values. I tried zooming in and I see that the data is not snapped. But this is not the case with ArcGIS Pro, which is doing Select by Location perfectly & upon zooming in the points are snapped to the line.

The Projection is same for both the files.

Why is there this discrepancy in location?

ArcGIS Pro Screenshot is here

[image: ArcGIS Pro Screenshot is here]

Below is the QGIS screenshot.

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

Comment: Could you share your data?

Comment: Check the projection of your map frame in each and see if it aligns with the projection of your data.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the coordinate references, but it seems ArcGIS is applying the datum transformation correctly.

Comment: I checked the Project properties on both, and they both were WGS84 UTM 45N, as per the Shapefiles

Comment: It's possible that ArcGIS PRO truncate the coordinate to a "reasonable" length (ie. not expecting you to provide nanometer accuracy...) while QGIS use all the decimal. So when checking for overlap ArcGIS consider the coordinate to be equal while QGIS see a very small difference... (try to mesure the distance between the point and the line in QGIS to see if my idea hold)

Comment: The difference is 0.49mm